# SlikelySubtags.json not loaded

Tags: javascript, cldr, javascript-globalize

I use `cldr` and `globalize` libaries. And I read in [docs](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/cldr.md) that I need to load `likelySubtags.json`.
Maybe, it is due to my poor English but I can't get where I need to get these files? Or how to generate?
Just for example:

```
<script>
Globalize.load({
  main: {
    en: {
      ...
    }
  },
  supplemental: {
    likelySubtags: {
      ...
    },
    timeDate: {
      ...
    },
    weekData: {
      ...
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

As I understood it generates these JSONs. But that do I need to write instead of points?
Can anyone explain more clear?
Below the code that I need to use if it has any value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        Globalize.locale('en');
        // Fix a date validation on the WebKit engine
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value, { skeleton: 'dd.MM.yyyy'});
        }
    });
</script>
```

P.S. Maybe, it's not difficult but I really can't get docs.

**ADDED**
This is an error that I get now:

> Uncaught Error: E_MISSING_CLDR: Missing required CLDR content
>   `supplemental/likelySubtags`.
>       at createError (globalize.js:105)
>       at validate (globalize.js:182)
>       at EventEmitter.validateCldr (globalize.js:204)
>       at EventEmitter.emitEvent (event.js:416)
>       at EventEmitter.aliasClosure [as trigger] (event.js:88)
>       at Cldr.get (event.js:572)
>       at validateLikelySubtags (globalize.js:337)
>       at Function.Globalize.locale (globalize.js:392)
>       at HTMLDocument. (Index:1892)
>       at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)

Of course, I understand that I need to call `Globalize.load()` before using it but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`likelySubtags.json` is a file from CLDR: https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-core/blob/master/supplemental/likelySubtags.json.

You can find the answer for your question at Globalize docs [How do I get CLDR data](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/cldr.md):

> ### How do I get CLDR data?
>
> *By downloading the JSON packages individually...*
>
> Unicode CLDR is available as JSON at https://github.com/unicode-cldr/ (after this [json-packaging proposal](http://cldr.unicode.org/development/development-process/design-proposals/json-packaging) took place). Please, read https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-json for more information about packageorganization.
>
> *By using a package manager...*
>
> `cldr-data` can be used for convenience. It always downloads from the correct source.
>
> Use npm `npm install cldr-data` or bower `bower install cldr-data` ([detailed instructions](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-bower)). For more information, see:
>
> - https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-npm
> - https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-bower

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yeah, I saw these repositories but I can't find where this JSON file. I reviewed few repos that had suitable name but no one has this file. The guide is enough difficult for me to understand but I will try to get it yet once.

Comment: Mm ok got it. I've edited my answer with a link specific to supplemental/likelySubtags.json. Please just let me know if you have any suggestions on how we can improve the docs. Thanks

Comment: This was ridiculously difficult to find (+hour of google-fu). In the case of VS, installing another package manager on top of NuGet (and there's no NuGet package for this), is not optimal. Thank you for the reference!