# Using Function which uses globalize causes Error in Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Im using Globalize from globalize package and have a function as below.

```
  getSeperator(): string {
        return Globalize(navigator.language).numberFormatter()(0.5).substring(1, 2);
    }
```

But When I test  a function which uses this/this function  I get the following error :

Error: E_MISSING_CLDR: Missing required CLDR content `supplemental/likelySubtags`

Spec.ts :

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NumPadComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  registerLocaleData('en');
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NumPadComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

What Am I Missing ?

EDIT : the use of the getSeperator function

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.seperator = Libs.getSeperator();
  }
```

Comment: Can you show how `getSeparator` method is used?

Comment: @Buczkowski added it, Its just calling this function. The reason im getting it without any IT block is caus its in the onInit i assume.

Comment: would be good to mock it (`Libs.getSeparator`) since error probably appear because something missing from `Globalize`.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155568/slikelysubtags-json-not-loaded

Comment: I dont understand how I could apply that in a unit test @GunnarB.

Comment: Did you install that json like in that answer?

Comment: yes, it works when I run my application normally @GunnarB.

Comment: created a spy and went ahead as @Buczkowski suggested. almost half a day trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Clueless: Can you share code of `Lib` initialization in component ? any reason for not injecting it via component `constructor` ? Also can you provide the link of npm for `Globalize` which you are using. is it https://www.npmjs.com/package/@code-art/angular-globalize ?